# Placing two divs next to each other on top of parent element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place two divs next to each other but and on the top of the parent div but within the borders of the parent

I've tried with to set `position:relative` to the parent and `position:relative` to kids but didnt manage do make `z-index` work

The logic i go with is to set the outter border to the parent element and add background-color and border to the icon but z-index keeps on not working

Here is the what I'm trying to build:

[image: Here is the photo of what i'am trying to build]

```css
.filters-select {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  border: var(--backgroud-color) solid 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.filters-select i {
  /* dont know what goes here*/
}

.filters-select span {
  /* dont know what goes here*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="filters-select">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-money-bill-1"></i>
  <span>Low cost</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This must be a school assignment. Or [déjà vu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626163/how-can-i-style-a-round-icon-element-inside-a-bordered-oval). Is "Confused" in your class?

Answer (score 0):

For the .filters-select i, you want to add your styling there to make it look like what you have in the picture. change the size, add some padding, give it a background and font color.

```
.filters-select i {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    padding: 1.3rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #deebff;
    color: #0065fc;
}
```

then you want .filters-select to have that border radius, but you may have to adjust the size of your .filters-select span so that it fits perfectly inside.

Comment: Ye ye design is not the problem, only positioning is. I managed to do it actually, it had to go with relative and absolute position. Tnx anyway